# HTTP POST request to C# Controller

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make HTTP POST request to my C# controller, but I need to send in data an array, so I tried with JSON.stringify but when I start debugging, the input parameter in my controller is NULL? 
I'm receiving a list from external API for weather forecast, so I need to create for each item in list new variable, that has some fields like : max and min temperature, description, humidity, pressure etc, and then of course fill these fields with data and add that variable to my array. Then I need to pass this array to my controller so I could store it in my database...
What type should I put in my controller so it would not be NULL? I'm totally new here so please help, any help is really more then welcome!

Below is code I have just to try :

```
 var myData = { id:100, description:"some text"};
 var myDataArray= new Array();   
 myDataArray.push(myData);   
 $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Weather1/Weather_post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(myDataArray),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(("OK"));
    },
    error: function (error)
    { console.log("NOT OK"); }
})
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Weather_post(String MyModuleList)
```

Comment: Show the method signature of the controller action.  We can't see why the method is failing without seeing the method.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Weather_post(String MyModuleList)

Comment: You don't seem to have anything on the client-side that corresponds to your parameter name: `MyModuleList`  Without that correspondence the parameter will always be `null`.  Try something like `data: { MyModuleList: JSON.stringify(myDataArray) }`

Comment: thanks David, it didn't actually work like this, but when I add stringify to all, it works. But now I have String, how to convert it to type I want? Please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Model binding has no idea what "MyModuleList" is. You can use a strongly typed model here and MVC will bind the JSON to it.

Consider JSON:

```
var data = {
    moduleList: [
        { id:100, description:"some text"}
    ];
};
```

and models:

```
public class ModuleListModel
{
    public List<ModuleModel> ModuleList { get; set; }
}
public class ModuleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Weather_post(ModuleListModel model)
{ 
    ... 
}
```

Combine that with @Timothy Shields' answer:

> You're missing processData: false in your ajax call. Without that,
>   ajax is going to try to pack the data into the URL query string. (See
>   here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had something like this, but I had to change just a few things, so you really helped me!

Answer (score 3):

You're missing `processData: false` in your `ajax` call. Without that, `ajax` is going to try to pack the `data` into the URL query string. (See here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

If `data` is `{ 'animal': 'elephant', 'count': 5 }` and `processData` is `true` (the default), `ajax` will do the `POST` to the URL `/Weather1/Weather_post?animal=elephant&count=5` with an empty HTTP request body. This is why you want `processData: false`.

Comment: still not OK, if I don't use stringify it doesn't send that request, but with stringify it does but input parameter is still null...

Comment: I tried to upvote but I can't since I'm new here and my reputation is only 6...will do when I get to 15

Comment: +1 from me plus a little guilt for referencing your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
 var myData = { id:100, description:"some text"};
 var myDataArray= new Array();   
 myDataArray.push(myData); 
 var param = JSON.stringify(myDataArray);  
 $.ajax({
     dataType: "json",
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Weather1/Weather_post",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: {'MyModuleList': param },
     success: function (data) {
          console.log(("OK"));
     },
     error: function (error)
     { console.log("NOT OK"); }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass the parameter name with the data. Something like:

```
 data: {'MyModuleList': JSON.stringify(myDataArray)},
```

See if this works for you.