# Linq to remove string from list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

When I click on a link from a list of names, I want it to be removed from the list. I have search a lot about LINQ and it seems that `RemoveAll` should do the job, but I get this annoying message when I call the Action in the Controller:

> *The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'.*

If I interpret this correctly I'm trying to pass a INT to the Action method!?

This is the list of strings in the Model:

```
public static List<string> listOfNames = new List<string>();
```

This is the html actionlink(I have also tested to use a query string):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item, "DeleteNameList", new { Id = item })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This is the action method in the Controller:

```
public ActionResult DeleteNamelist(string nameToDelete)
{
    return View("NameInput", NameModel.listOfNames.RemoveAll(x => x == nameToDelete));
}
```

Comment: [`RemoveAll` returns an `int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx)... You should run `NameModel.listOfNames.RemoveAll()` and *then* pass the collection to your view. Your current code is giving the view the number of items removed, not the collection itself.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your comment, but I'm not sure I follow what you mean? Could you make an answer whith a short example of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is doing this:

```
public ActionResult DeleteNamelist(string nameToDelete)
{
    int numRemoved = NameModel.listOfNames.RemoveAll(x => x == nameToDelete);
    return View("NameInput", numRemoved);
}
```

Which means you are passing an `int` to the view. You should be doing this:

```
public ActionResult DeleteNamelist(string nameToDelete)
{
    NameModel.listOfNames.RemoveAll(x => x == nameToDelete);
    return View("NameInput", NameModel.listOfNames);
}
```

Comment: I believe the last line should be `return View("NameInput", NameModel.listIfNames)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen Yes, you're right - my bad (saw `Model` and just assumed it was the model :)). Thanks @dotctor for ths fix

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I get a red line below NameModel in the return. The error message is: 'NameModel' is a type which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Yes I saw the edit and added that and the page is running, but the names is still in the list! What could be wrong?

Comment: @front-back Most likely it's not perfectly matching `nameToDelete` - you'll have to debug a bit

Comment: OK, it's working if I run it like this:  NameModel.listOfNames.RemoveAll(x => x == "Anna");

Comment: @Rob I discovered that in only works like this: ` @Html.ActionLink(item, "DeleteNameList", new { nameToDelete = item })` and then I get a ? in the URL. Why isn't the other way working? Is it a routing thing?

Comment: @front-back The only other way to do it is with a `POST`. The `?` is required as it's defining the parameters to be passed to your controller method.

Comment: @Rob I added the [HttpPost] before the action but then I get a message that the resource could not be found . Have I missed something?

Comment: @front-back Yes, `[HttpPost]` means your controller will only *accept* `POST` requests, it doesn't actually change the request. Making a `POST` request is significantly different from a `GET` request, in that you'll need to write some javascript to make the request, rather than simply using `ActionLink`. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662680/http-post-request-to-c-sharp-controller for an idea of what's involved in making a `POST` request. This comment thread is getting a tad derailed from the original question, so I'll leave it at that for now

Comment: OK Thanks for your help!

Comment: @front-back No worries mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your value to action is not going correct.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(item, "DeleteNameList", new { nameToDelete = item })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

After that in controller use:

```
public ActionResult DeleteNamelist(string nameToDelete)
{
   NameModel.listOfNames.RemoveAll(x => x == nameToDelete);
   return View("NameInput", NameModel.listOfNames);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way:

```
public ActionResult DeleteNamelist(string nameToDelete)
{
    return View("NameInput", NameModel.listOfNames.Where(x => x != nameToDelete));

}
```